# VBA Click Link in IE Ajax PopUp

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate the process of downloading a CSV from a web site.

I've managed to write the code to:

1. Log in to the site
2. Navigate to the correct page
3. Click the link to make the download accessible.

From there, my problem begins.  Upon clicking the link, the site does a series of Ajax calls and displays a div with a link to download the file that has a unique name each time.   I can get the box to pop up, but I cannot get the VBA to click the link after it becomes available.  Can anybody help with getting VBA to click the link in the box that is displayed after the ajax call?

```
Sub GetTableData()
    Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDoc As Object

    Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
    ieApp.Visible = True

    ieApp.Navigate "https://www.thesite.com/Login.aspx"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

    On Error GoTo downloadPage
    testPage = ieDoc.getElementById("file_box_link_id")

     With ieDoc
         .getElementById("EMail").Value = "me@web.com"
         .getElementById("Password").Value = "pass"
         .getElementById("Submit").Click
     End With

     Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

     ieApp.Navigate "https://www.thesite.com/Menu.aspx"
     Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
downloadPage:

    ieDoc.getElementById("download_link").Click
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop



    '  THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM COMES...THIS HTML IS ADDED AFTER THE AJAX CALL
    dlLink = ieDoc.getElementById("download_link")
    Debug.Print dlLink.href




    ieApp.Quit
    Set ieApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Not [mcve] as far as I can tell. How would be debug this pop-up pressing? There is no HTML for it shown?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can get any data from the pop-up, but if you can, try to use getElementsByTagName method and the outerText property.

```
For Each Link In ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("a") Do
   If Link.outerText = "The link text" Then
      Link.Click
      Exit For
   End If
Next
```

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hope it help!

Best regards,
Luiz Fernando

Comment: That's still not doing it.  I believe the problem is that the `ieDoc` is not updating with the new contents after the AJAX call.